# How to set audio Gain using fraunhofer decoder on iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to iphone and currently struck.

Could anyone tell me as how to set the Gain of a audio buffer by using the fraunhofer decoder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although stackoverflow.com is a popular place for such questions, I think something this specific is best asked on [the official Cocos2D-iPhone forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/).